# When to use iterative methods for solving systems of linear equation

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Iterative methods such as Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel method and successive over relaxation have a very limited field of use - for diagonally dominant matrices. So how they could be used on practice? What is the advantages over methods which calculates the exact result? I especially interested in SOR method, which often worse then Gauss-Seidel and selecting a good SOR parameter to overcome Gauss-Seidel method is hard?
I already found that SOR useful for solving Poison's equation

Comment: For huge systems (think $10^9 \times 10^9$), iterative approaches are a must for performance. My preference are CG-like algorithms such as pcg.

Comment: I understand that other algorithms which work with any systems  are good  for solving huge systems. But I couldn't understand where they applied because of their limitation

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? They are general purpose algorithms, so you can apply them anywhere where a numerical solution is acceptable.

Comment: Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel used for strictly diagonally dominant matrices

Comment: Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel, and SOR are frankly rather primitive methods; it bothers me a little bit that my numerical analysis class spent so much time on them, when they are only practical in rather limited situations. They are decent for things like discretizations of the Dirichlet Poisson equation (which is weakly diagonally dominant, with strict dominance in the boundary condition equations), but we have more powerful and specialized methods like multigrid for these "easy" problems. On the flip side, there are much more general methods out there, such as the class of Krylov subspace methods.

Comment: I suspected this methods are only theoretic. Anyway may be you know other special appliances of this methods?

Comment: @Ian Just a few comments: Relaxations are pretty useless for discretized PDEs (Poisson equation as well), their convergence rate strongly depends on the discretization parameter. Multigrid is what actually makes these methods useful in this context due to their smoothing properties.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I'd forgotten about that. I remember that there is an eigenvalue variant, like in $\Delta u - u = f$, where everything is nicer because you have strict dominance.

Comment: @IvanEhreshi As AlgebraicPavel pointed out, one good application is as a subroutine in a larger method like multigrid, where the ultimate goal is to solve a huge system arising from a fine discretization, but the procedure starts from a relatively small system arising from a coarse system and proceeds by refinement. The coarse systems can sometimes be solved by cheap/simple methods like Jacobi iteration.

Comment: @Ian True, I've forgot about that :)